# What is the jquery selector for strong/bold text?

Tags: jquery

I need two selectors:

- one for ordinary text in a `h2` element
- and one for text within a `strong` tag

The first is working with:

`selector: 'h2.flashHeader'`

But

`selector: 'h2.flashHeader strong'`

doesn't work for string text.. any ideas?

Markup:

```
<h2 class="flashHeader">
            <umbraco:Item field="headerText" stripParagraph="true" runat="server"></umbraco:Item>
        </h2>
```

The Umbraco field embeds text that comes in two variants - normal and strong, like so:

```
<h2 class="flashHeader">
            <strong>Strong text.</strong>
some other not strong text
        </h2>
```

Comment: So in your markup, the 'strong' is inside of the h2.flashHeader?

Comment: Post your markup or else nobody's going to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: `$('h2.flashHeader strong')` is correct if the `strong` is inside the `h2` element. If that's the case, you're doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure it uses a `<strong></strong>` tag set? Have you used Firefox/Firebug (for example) to view the resulting markup?

Comment: Yes I have. I'm using it in conjunction with sifr so the if the selector is right then sifr must be the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<h2 class="flashHeader">
  Stack <strong>Overflow</strong>
</h2>
```

Then your selectors should be working.

Answer (score 3):

`$('strong')` is the jQuery selector for strong / bold text.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, 'strong' will pick up all `<strong>` tags, but it won't pick up text marked as bold using CSS.